# sys.stdin and sys.stdout report AttributeError

Tags: python

I tried to test sys.stdin and sys.stdout as cin and cout in cpp

```
In [4]: sys.stdin = "read"   
In [5]: sys.stdout = sys.stdin                                                                                                                         

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@python.org
```

How could get such a pattern working?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What is your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as `std::cin` and `std::cout` in C++, Python's `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` are **not strings but text streams**.

To read from, resp. write to a stream, C++ uses the operators `>>`, resp. `<<`:

```
std::cin >> spam;
std::cout << spam;
```

Python's equivalent of this are the methods `read()` and `write()` of text stream objects:

```
spam = sys.stdin.read()
sys.stdout.write(spam)
```

In order to send arbitrary data to stdin, you need to create a new stream object, such as `io.StringIO` – something from which you can `read()`:

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> sys.stdin = StringIO('spam')
>>> sys.stdin.read()
'spam'
```